# .Net Core MongoDB.Driver ObjectId Null from POCO Mapping

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am working with ASP.net Core, MongoDB.Driver 2.13.0, and a MongoDB document with the following structure:

```
 "lrec80" : [ 
    {
        "RR4NFAD" : {
            "$ref" : "RR4OCO",
            "$id" : ObjectId("00000000000000008c8a414b"),
            "$db" : "tpfdf"
        },
        "RR4NRCC" : 43,
        "RR4NAKY" : 0,
        "RR4NA80" : {
            "RR4NSDT" : { "$binary" : "UOE=", "$type" : "00" }
        },
        "RR4NPDT" : { "$binary" : "UOs=", "$type" : "00" },
        "RR4NTY1" : -124,
        "RR4NCTY" : "IAH",
        "RR4NLIA" : null,
        "RR4NNBR" : 1
    },
```

My POCO objects maps almost all the fields I need, with the exception of the "RR4NFAD" object.

```
public class RR4NFAD
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("$ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("$db")]
    public string DB { get; set; }
}
```

If I set Id property to ObjectId type, I get the **DB** and **Ref** fields successfully, but **Id** field shows the following:

```
Id = {000000000000000000000000}
CreationTime = 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
Increment = 0
Machine = 0
Pid = 0
Timestamp = 0
```

If I set Id field to string:

```
   public class RR4NFAD
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("$ref")]
    public string Ref { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("$db")]
    public string DB { get; set; }
}
```

**Id returns as null**, but I still get the **DB** and **Ref** fields successfully

I've tried creating a ObjectIdConverter without success and applying it as an attribute on the Id field using the following example:

[Returning ObjectID as a string from ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41345401/returning-objectid-as-a-string-from-asp-net-core)

How can I get the RR4NFAD Id field to return as one of the following as a reference to query another document?

- ObjectId("00000000000000008c8a414b")
- "00000000000000008c8a414b"

Thanks for any help you can offer. Seems like a simple problem, but I'm new to MongoDB and it's giving me fits.

Comment: `BsonId` should be set only for top level `Id` which will be transformed into `_id` field, in your case, you should use `BsonNoIdAttribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue & Concern**

According to [MongoDB forum's comment from James_Kovacs](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/working-with-id-in-net/122599/3),

The .NET/C# driver automatically adds an `_id` member if you don’t assign one explicitly. The driver automatically maps the `Id` property of a class to the `_id` field in the database. You can override this with class mapping attributes or code configuration if desired.

This is why your `Id` in `RR4NFAD` class will not able to get the value as it is being translated to `_id` instead of `Id`.

---

**Solution**

Implement the [Class Map](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/) to override the default behavior of [`Id` member](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.13/reference/bson/mapping/#the-id-member).

```cs
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<RR4NFAD>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.UnmapProperty(c => c.Id);
    cm.MapMember(c => c.Id)
        .SetElementName("$id");
});
```

> Demo

[image]